# My developer account is different from my admob account .Is there any risk involved?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I published my app in google play store recently. I just want to know whether there would be any problem as my admob account is different from my developer account ?

Comment: No issue with different account , you can have different admob account instead of having same as developer account.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!